# MySQL count specific column after group by

Tags: mysql

I want to count a specific column after a group by, but the result is different as my expected. Here is the case: Let say I have a table with these data:

```
sdate           name    collected
2017-01-01      John    5
2017-01-01      John    3
2017-01-01      Wick    6
2017-01-01      Wick    6
2017-01-02      Mary    5
2017-01-02      Pete    1
2017-01-02      Mary    4
2017-01-02      Pete    2
2017-01-03      John    8
```

I want to get sum of `collected` by using the following query:

```
select name, sdate, sum(collected) as count from test 
group by name, sdate 
order by sdate
```

Output:

```
sdate           name    count 
2017-01-01      wick    9
2017-01-01      john    11
2017-01-02      pete    3
2017-01-02      mary    9
2017-01-03      john    8
```

PROBLEM: I want to `select count(name) group by sdate` from the result above, so the result will be:

```
sdate           name    count    countName
2017-01-01      wick    9        2
2017-01-01      john    11       2
2017-01-02      pete    3        2
2017-01-02      mary    9        2
2017-01-03      john    8        1
```

How to achieve this? I have tried to do it with statement below:

```
select A.*, count(A.name) as countName
from 
(select sdate, name, sum(collected) as count from test 
group by name, sdate 
order by sdate) A
group by A.sdate
```

output:

```
sdate       name    count   countName
2017-01-01  wick    9       2
2017-01-02  mary    9       2
2017-01-03  john    8       1
```

the counts are correct, but number of rows will be grouped, which is what I dont want. Any idea how to achieve it without rows being removed?

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what you want but it seems you want to know how many rows are in each group. Add `count(*) as countName` to the original query:

```
select name, sdate, sum(collected) as count, count(*) as countName
from test
group by name, sdate 
order by sdate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name, sdate, sum(collected) as count, count(*) as countName
from test 
group by name, sdate 
order by sdate;
```

Comment: dont forget to add `COUNT(*)` also.